# Distorted border radius when scaling a react-native-reanimated Animated.View scaleX and scaleY with different values

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to animate a view growing in size with react-native-reanimated. The scale factors scaleX and scaleY are derived dynamically based on the view's size and position, and can be different. For example.

```
animatedScaleX.value = withTiming(1.2, {
            duration,
            easing: Easing.quad
        })
        animatedScaleY.value = withTiming(2, {
            duration,
            easing: Easing.quad
        })
```

This distorts the `borderRadius` of the `Animated.View`. How can I keep the radius as the same while scaling X and Y with different values? Or is this something that should be tried to be achieved with animating SVGs or avoided altogether?

Thanks!

I tried to use an animated value also for the radius `borderRadius: animatedBorderRadius.value` but this didn't work either.